# Send payment receipt to customer

Tags: paypal, payment, paypal-ipn, receipt

I have pay button on my website. I want to send receipt to customer email about the details of the product that they just bought, i.e. product dimensions, product history, product manual. How to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your button does not use an API to capture, then [use webhooks or IPN to receive the notification](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/) on your webserver, and send the email from there.